# Why does sbt fail with java.io.IOException: Permission denied at startup?

Tags: sbt

I've installed sbt on Mac OS X 10.9 via MacPorts.
If I run sbt as root - all works fine, but as a user - I got an exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileOrSubdirectoryNamed(AbstractFile.scala:235)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileNamed(AbstractFile.scala:246)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:34)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.scala$tools$nsc$backend$jvm$BytecodeWriters$$getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:37)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$ClassBytecodeWriter$class.writeClass(BytecodeWriters.scala:89)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase$$anon$4.writeClass(GenASM.scala:67)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JBuilder.writeIfNotTooBig(GenASM.scala:459)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JMirrorBuilder.genMirrorClass(GenASM.scala:2980)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:114)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(Eval.scala:159)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:159)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:159)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.atPhase(SymbolTable.scala:207)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:159)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:164)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:135)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.eval(Eval.scala:86)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSetting(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:144)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:106)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:105)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:105)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:507)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:502)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:501)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:501)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.Load$.loadSettings$1(Load.scala:500)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expand$1(Load.scala:523)
at sbt.Load$.loadSettings(Load.scala:528)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSbtFiles$1(Load.scala:464)
at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:475)
at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:478)
at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:418)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:419)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:312)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:264)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:260)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:251)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:134)
at sbt.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:613)
at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:579)
at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:567)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:411)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:312)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:264)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:260)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:251)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:134)
at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:37)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:473)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:179)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:100)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:93)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

~/.sbt/* ~/.ivy2/* are owned by my user
/opt/local/share/sbt - in which sbt script and sbt-launch.jar resides has 777 permission with this files.

Seems sbt wants to create file somewhere and fails, if you don't know exact solution for this, please advise how can I debug. Is it possible to see some sbt log, or maybe there is some system tool to define where sbt want to create the file.

Thanks in advise.

Comment: Have you tried to install SBT without sudo/root?

Comment: I want sbt to be installed via MacPorts (mostly because it will update sbt automatically) and MacPorts require root for installing packages. I believe installing sbt without root will solve the issue, but I will do this only if I know that no other solutions exists.

Comment: Where do you execute `sbt`? Is the directory owned properly? It appears as if compilation couldn't save an output file. I'd bet it's `target` in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, I run sbt in project directory which is owned by me. I guess compilation error is not the case because even if I run `sbt about` which is not intended to compile project, crashes with exception - so it seems like issue  during sbt initialisation

Comment: Can you do `sbt about` with `-Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2 -Dsbt.global.base=./sbt` defined with custom directories? Something like `SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2 -Dsbt.global.base=./sbt" sbt about`?

Comment: Got the same exception

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace? Can you run `sudo opensnoop -n java > output.sbt.txt` and while `opensnoop` is monitoring the files open, execute `sbt about`? You may also have more luck with `sudo dtruss sbt about` or `sudo iosnoop -n java > output.sbt.txt`. Review the output files to learn about the files expected.

Comment: I provided full trace (it's scrolling there). Iosnoop and opensnoop doesn't work for me (didn't have much time to figure out why) and dtruss seems to run sbt as root so it should work without issues and it trace i didn't find files wich it has not permissions to read or write to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One cause of this problem might be that you ran sbt as root :).  When you did that, sbt created things in your directory (like the target directories) as root, and now they're owned by root. When you re-run sbt as yourself, you can't access those directories anymore.

You now either have to fix all of the directory/file ownerships/permissions, or delete them all. When you re-run sbt from your account, it will re-create those directories/files under your account, and it will work.

If you're working from a git repo, just re-clone the project and re-run sbt as yourself instead of root.

Comment: Or just do: `sudo chown -R youruser:yourgroup .`